How to have clickable text that opens a pdf with href
This is the latex document I have:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{run:./G.pdf}{Clickable link 1}
\href{run:./G}{Clickable link 1}
\end{document}

I want the Clickable links to be clickable such that they open the pdf I've uploaded to the overleaf document titled G. But when I download this and open the pdf, no result, it additionally doesn't show anything in the overleaf document either. I've tried others such as file: , \url{}. What are you supposed to do in this scenario?

Simply G.pdf or file:G.pdf should work, but it depends on the PDF viewer.

@Ulrike Instead of opening a new file (redirecting to the pdf), it instead goes to the first page of the latex document for \href{file:G.pdf}{something} or \href{G.pdf}{samething}

To answer your first question: In Overleaf after having created a document, there is a button in the top-left for uploading images and files which can be accessed by the original document, i.e. \displayimage. I uploaded a Firefox pdf titled G in my files. Since it sounds like possible problems with the pdf viewer, would it be possible to open the pdf in a new tab when clicking a phrase in the latex document, similar to \hyperref?

@IV-301 I see. Thanks for the clarification. I played around with Overleaf a bit. Seems Overleaf does not let you open file-links. Actually this is not a question about TeX or LaTeX but about how the web-interface Overleaf works. Probably you get better support by contacting Overleaf. To do so you can click on "Menu" in the top left and then scroll down to "? Contact Us".
